# Old bread becomes sticky

Tags: bread

Sometimes white bread, while initially fine,  after a few days becomes sticky inside  as if its going back to a dough-state, though not quite.  The taste also becomes odd.  Does anyone understand what is happening ...?  Heating/drying it in various ways does not help (e.g. steaming, microwave, toasting etc)

i think i have seen this happen only with the small bakery breads, not the mass market variety...

thanks..

Comment: Very odd observation. Bread normally becomes stale, which is drier than fresh, not stickier. How do you store your bread? Could it be eaten up by mold? (But I can't imagine that a mold infestation strong enough to change the texture won't be recognized by sight and smell).

Comment: Do you live in a humid area? Bread only dries out if the air is drier than the bread.

Comment: I've observed the same thing. I do live in a humid area, but I'd expect the bread to become soft and chewy. However, it gets very sticky in some spots after 3 days or so. And toasting it just make the sticky spots a bit softer and even more sticky.

Comment: How did you keep it? That essential information is missing from your question, [edit] it in.

Answer (score 6):

This almost sounds like rope spoilage. From what I've read on various bread blogs, rope spores will cause a typical loaf of bread to deteriorate very quickly in exactly the manner you describe: the center becomes doughy and stretchy. My understanding is that the rope spores can contaminate kitchens and become a real problem for baked goods.

I had a hard time coming up with details on it, but you might want to check the following link for a picture and description:

http://www.intechopen.com/books/advances-in-applied-biotechnology/fermentation-processes-using-lactic-acid-bacteria-producing-bacteriocins-for-preservation-and-improv

I first read about rope spoilage years ago on a bread forum called [The Fresh Loaf.](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/8539/rope-thankful-small-kitchen)

You may also want to check with your local agricultural extension service. There might be testing available.

Comment: Of interest:  http://www.emlab.com/s/sampling/FoodMicroGlossary.html#rope_spore_count  It looks like decontaminating can also be quite difficult sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced this for the first time after making our own bread for years.  A 3 day old loaf became sticky to touch, the crumb coming away on fingers, almost impossible to slice as the blade drags through the crumb.
I binned it to be on the safe side